# Variable replacement in string

Tags: c#, data-structures, logic, asp.net-core-2.0

Developing an application in c# to replace variables across strings.

Need suggestions how to do that very efficiently?

```
private string MyStrTr(string source, string frm, string to)
    {
        char[] input = source.ToCharArray();
        bool[] replaced = new bool[input.Length];

       for (int j = 0; j < input.Length; j++)
            replaced[j] = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < frm.Length; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j<input.Length;j++)
                if (replaced[j] == false && input[j]==frm[i])
                {
                    input[j] = to[i];
                    replaced[j] = true;
                }
        }
        return new string(input);
    }
```

Above code works fine but each variables need to traverse across string according to variable count.

Exact requirement.

```
parent.name = am;
parent.number = good;
I {parent.name} a {parent.number} boy.
output should be I am a good boy.
```

think like source will be huge.

For example if i have 5 different variable need to traverse full string 5 times.

Need a suggestions how to process the variables parellely during first time traversal?

Comment: so if `source` is "aaaaa" and `frm` is "abc" and `to` is "xyz" you want the output to be "xxxx"?  If so creating a `Dictionary<char, char>` from `frm` and `to` then you can just loop the `source` once.

Comment: @juharr if source is `"i am a boy"`, variables are i`i = Hi, am = how, a = are, boy = you`
It should be `"Hi How are you"`

this like source will be huge.

Comment: have you tried regex? it is very fast and secure. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: You mean you call it 4 times?  I don't see how it will replace "i" with "Hi" when it loops over the length of `frm` and replaces with the corresponding index in `to` meaning if they are different lengths you either get an exception or  you don't get all the values from `to`

Comment: @juharr give me any suggestion if this does not work.

Comment: @juharr updated question

Comment: Any reason you cannot just use `string.Replace`.  Based on the latest update something like `var output = input.Replace("{parent.name}", parent.name).Replace("{parent.number}", parent.number)` is what you want.

Comment: @juharr if my string is huge also number of variables will change dynamically.At that time string.replace wont work.

Comment: Seems like you'd want to scan the string and find everything from the first `{` to the closing `}` then do a lookup on the string inside of that.  You can do that with loops or as already suggested you could attempt it with regular expressions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181402/discussion-between-boopathi-and-juharr).

Comment: When you say that your source string will be huge, just how large are you talking?

Comment: @Jim Mischel Huge like Terms and conditions content of fb or WhatsApp

Answer (score 0):

I think you're suffering from premature optimization. Write the simplest thing first and see if it works for you. If you don't suffer a performance problem, then you're done. Don't waste time trying to make it faster when you don't know how fast it is, or if it's the cause of your performance problem.

By the way, Facebook's Terms of Service, the entire HTML page that includes a lot of Javascript, is only 164 kilobytes. That's not especially large.

[String.Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Replace_System_String_System_String_) should work quite well, even if you have multiple strings to replace. That is, you can write:

```
string result = source.Replace("{parent.name}", "am");
result = result.Replace("{parent.number}", "good");
// more replacements here

return result;
```

That will exercise the garbage collector a little bit, but it shouldn't be a problem unless you have a truly massive page or a whole mess of replacements.

You can potentially save yourself some garbage collection by converting the string to a [StringBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=netframework-4.7.2), and calling [StringBuilder.Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder.replace?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Text_StringBuilder_Replace_System_String_System_String_) multiple times. I honestly don't know, though, whether that will have any appreciable effect. I don't know how `StringBuilder.Replace` is implemented.

There is a way to make this faster, by writing code that will parse the string and do all the replacements in a single pass. It's a lot of code, though. You have to build a state machine from the multiple search strings and go through the `source` text one character at a time. It's doable, but it's a difficult enough task that you probably don't want to do it unless the simple method flat doesn't work quickly enough.